# Unable for format Mini PC - X5 with Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, uefi

I recently purchased a X5 Mini PC from the following [site](https://www.lazada.sg/products/x5-mini-pc-intel-atom-x5-z8350-support-windows-10-android-51-intl-i164660188-s211105312.html) and was trying to have a clean install of Windows 10 instead of the pre-install copy with android.

During the installation process, I was thrown with an error stating that "Setup was unable to create a new system partition: Fix for Windows".

1. I have tried to work on this for a couple of nights along with this
   [guide](https://neosmart.net/wiki/setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition/) to use diskpart to pre-format and prepare the disk. But
   it didn't work, the same error still occurred.
2. Others suggest that it could be an UEFI locked issue and I should disable the secure boot option. However, the APTIO Setup Utility does not provide me with any option. I tried adding administrator password in security, hoping that it would enable the option as other suggest, but it failed to work.

Does anyone have similar experience or is familiar with BIOS and UEFI to lend a hand? Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try another hard drive?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321The hard drive is probably soldered onto the motherboard, the only other option I tried was to boot it with Ubuntu through a USB. However, it doesn't boot directly even though I have the boot options set properly. I will have to override the boot option everytime I start up.

Comment: It is not common practice to solder a hard drive into the motherboard.

Comment: Why are you creating partitions by hand. Just delete all the partitions and allow the installation environment create them.

Comment: **Never** trust anything written by NeoSmart.  They are absolutely the worst company and none of their software should ever touch your system.  I speak from experience.  Their software made a potential easy problem, extremely more difficult to solve, and they were absolutely no help.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I believe they might be using some sort of flash storage, but for such a small pc, I doubt there's any hard disk in it, it is likely to be some sort of SD card or flash memory.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the headsup. I tried a couple of other sites with similar solutions but to no avail. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you attempting to format the 32gb ROM or the SD Card?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I am trying to reformat the "HDD", SD card in the computer

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the error message in question?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I don't have the screenshot with me right now, but the message I get if I clear all partitions and click next to install result in this error message:  "Windows could not prepare the computer to boot into the next phase of installation"

Comment: What happens when you clear all partitions, make a new one, then reboot back into Setup, then click next?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 At the harddisk selection page, I deleted all partition and selected an unallocated space to write Windows into. Usually, this would automatically create all the required partitions and install. But my installation throws an error.

Comment: What happens when you create the partition before clicking next, filling up all unallocated space?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 It will throw the first error: "setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition"

Comment: Can you format the SD Card on another system? If not, get a new SD Card.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I was able to format it using diskpart.exe

Comment: After you have formatted the SD card using Diskpart, have you attempted to install Windows on the created partition? (Clicking the partition before clicking Next)

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 The error I got was this: "Windows is unable to install to the selected location."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into this problem sometimes at work and it usually comes down to [re-downloading the ISO](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-and-office-iso-download-tool) and remaking your USB with [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) I have used both of these tools and have made sure that they are legit /virus free.

Comment: I'm sure a damaged ISO can create a partition if it can read the drive/boot at all...

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 it depends on which part of the ISO is damaged. I just stated what has worked for me in the past.

Comment: @reddaugherty Are you suggesting that the ISO is damaged?

Comment: @reddaugherty The iso was fitted in by the windows provided usb maker.

Answer (score 0):

Your SD card has underlying corruption. You can format it, but the data cannot be physically written to. Use another SD Card.

Comment: The computer running well before I reformatted it. It is unlikely that it gets corrupted just after deleting the partitions.

Comment: It is better to try and use another SD Card on your sustem, so we know if the answer worked or not.

Comment: Yeah I would love to, but the system seems to be built in. Can't really move it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Windows 10 installation USB from the ISO file, go to the Windows 10 Home installation, select Custom, delete all partition drives, and create a new partition, install. There will be no wifi, you connect to the network from android phone with micro USB will automatically update wifi device, no audio device, intel hd graphics device, bluetooth device go to (https://drp.su/en/laptops / deeq / x5-z8350) to download and install. Windows 10 Home auto active